# Code Refactoring, Moving cells from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to refactor a part of a project that I am working on I have Two blocks of code that pretty much do the same thing except with a single variable changed  `(rowNum_partNum, 1)` and `(rowNum, 2)` in the other block. I can not split the two into separate functions as they both use a variable that is highly manipulated within the current function. I tried refactoring but I cant figure out what's wrong.

**Original Code that works:**

```
If PartNumber_Category_Selector() <> 0 Then
        If PartNumber_Category_Selector() = 1 Then
            Dim rowNum_partNum As Long
            Dim searchRow_PartNum As Long
            rowNum_partNum = 9
            searchRow_PartNum = 9
            Worksheets("DataBase").Activate
            Do Until Cells(rowNum_partNum, 1).Value = ""
                If InStr(1, Cells(rowNum_partNum, 1).Value, searchingItem, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow_PartNum, 1).Value = Cells(rowNum_partNum, 1).Value
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow_PartNum, 2).Value = Cells(rowNum_partNum, 2).Value
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow_PartNum, 3).Value = Cells(rowNum_partNum, 3).Value
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow_PartNum, 4).Value = Cells(rowNum_partNum, 4).Value
                    searchRow_PartNum = searchRow_PartNum + 1
                End If
                rowNum_partNum = rowNum_partNum + 1
            Loop
            
            If searchRow_PartNum = 9 Then
                MsgBox "No Results found"
            Else
                lst_leadTime.RowSource = "SearchResultsV5"
            End If
        ElseIf PartNumber_Category_Selector() = 2 Then
            Dim rowNum As Long
            Dim searchRow As Long
            rowNum = 9
            searchRow = 9
            Worksheets("DataBase").Activate
            Do Until Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = ""
                If InStr(1, Cells(rowNum, 2).Value, searchingItem, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow, 1).Value = Cells(rowNum, 1).Value
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow, 2).Value = Cells(rowNum, 2).Value
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow, 3).Value = Cells(rowNum, 3).Value
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow, 4).Value = Cells(rowNum, 4).Value
                    searchRow = searchRow + 1
                End If
                rowNum = rowNum + 1
            Loop
            
            If searchRow = 9 Then
                MsgBox "No Results found "
            Else
                lst_leadTime.RowSource = "SearchResultsV5"
                
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "No Results found "
        End If
    Else
       MsgBox "No Results found "
    End If
```

**Refactored code (Does not work):**

```
    If PartNumber_Category_Selector() <> 0 Then
            Dim rowNum_partNum As Long, searchRow_PartNum As Long, Selector As Byte
            rowNum_partNum = 9
            searchRow_PartNum = 9
            Selector = PartNumber_Category_Selector()
            Worksheets("DataBase").Activate
            Do Until Cells(rowNum_partNum, Selector).Value = ""
                If InStr(1, Cells(rowNum_partNum, Selector).Value, searchingItem, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow_PartNum, 1).Value = Cells(rowNum_partNum, 1).Value
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow_PartNum, 2).Value = Cells(rowNum_partNum, 2).Value
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow_PartNum, 3).Value = Cells(rowNum_partNum, 3).Value
                    Worksheets("LeadTimes").Cells(searchRow_PartNum, 4).Value = Cells(rowNum_partNum, 4).Value
                    searchRow_PartNum = searchRow_PartNum + 1
                End If
                rowNum_partNum = rowNum_partNum + 1
            Loop
            If searchRow = 9 Then
                MsgBox "No Results found "
            Else
                lst_leadTime.RowSource = "SearchResultsV5"
            End If
    End IF
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: `If searchRow = 9 Then` should probably be `If searchRow_PartNum = 9 Then` looks like you have mixed the two a bit. Using `Option Explicit` will help you catch these things.

Comment: You can use F8 to step through the code for debugging. You can safely have Selector as a long, and make sure the Loop will not go on forever.